# Tool or utility to test cache status

Tags: asp.net, testing, browser-cache

According to the requirement ,we have to remove proxy -cache from every ASP.NET web page.What is the best tool to test whether the proxy cache is removed from the page?

Answer (score 0):

IF the "removal" process is to delete an attribute from the aspx file then, simply use the Visual studio Edit/Find and Replace/Find in files, set the search string to the cache attribute that should have been removed and restrict the search to *.aspx.
Any results indicate pages that have not been ammended.